# Login Frontend React native #modal #webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, modal-dialog

I'm with only one error on this login screen. When I click I forgotmy password (Forgot password) I want a modal to appear with the respective site inside it. I made this code and it was working perfectly, however now is appearing this error message (null is not an object) Please help me  :(
I believe that the problem is in WebViewModal, because when I remove it, the modal is shown perfectly

```
import * as React from 'react';
    import { useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
    import {
        Text, StyleSheet,
        KeyboardAvoidingView, ScrollView, Image,
        TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View, SafeAreaView,
        Linking, Modal
    } from 'react-native';
    import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';
    import { Ionicons } from 'react-native-vector-icons'
    import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { Modalize } from 'react-native-modalize';
    import WebViewModalProvider, { WebViewModal } from
        'react-native-webview-modal';
    
    
    const Login = () => {
        const [input, setInput] = useState('');
        const [hidePass, setHidePass] = useState(true);
        const [ischecked1, setIschecked1] = useState(true);
        const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
        const navigation = useNavigation();
        const modalizeRef = useRef(null);
    
    
        function onOpen() {
            modalizeRef.current?.open();
        }
    
        return (
            
            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                style={styles.container}
            >
                <SafeAreaView>
                    <Modalize
                        ref={modalizeRef}
                        snapPoint={500}
                    //handlePosition="inside"
                    >
                        <View style={{
                            flex: 1, height: 500,
                            flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'
                        }}>
                            <WebViewModalProvider>
                                <View style={{ margin: 30, height: 500 }}>
                                    <SafeAreaView />
                                    <WebViewModal
                                        visible={true}
                                        source={{ uri: "https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/ChangePassword.aspx" }}
                                        style={{ margin: 10 }}
                                    />
                                </View>
                            </WebViewModalProvider>
                        </View>
                    </Modalize>
    
                    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    
                        <Image
                            source={require('../../assets/logo.png')}
                            style={styles.logo}
                        />
                        <Text style={styles.helloText}>
                            Olá de novo !
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>
                            Bem-vindo(a) de volta,
                            sentimos sua falta!
                        </Text>
    
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.inputArea}
                            placeholder="Digite o e-mail"
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.inputArea}
                            placeholder="Senha"
                            value={input}
                            onChangeText={(texto) => setInput(texto)}
                            secureTextEntry={hidePass}
                        />
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.eye} onPress={() => setHidePass(!hidePass)}>
                            <Ionicons name={hidePass ? 'eye' : 'eye-off'}
                                color="#A0D800" size={25}
                            />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <View style={styles.checkBoxStyle}>
                            <CheckBox
                                left
                                size={18}
                                checkedColor='#A0D800'
                                value={ischecked1}
                                checked={ischecked1}
                                onPress={() => setIschecked1(!ischecked1)}
    
                                containerStyle={{
                                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                                    borderColor: "transparent", marginRight: 0
                                }}
                            />
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setIschecked1(true)}>
                                <Text style={styles.Connected}>
                                    Manter-se conectado
                                </Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
    
                            <TouchableOpacity //onPress={() => 
                                // Linking.openURL('https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/ChangePassword.aspx')}
                                onPress={onOpen}>
                                <Text style={styles.forgotPassword}>
                                    Esqueci minha senha
                                </Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
    
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={styles.botao}
                            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("TabNavigator")}
                        >
                            <Text style={styles.botaoText}>Entrar</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
    
    
                    </ScrollView>
                </SafeAreaView>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    
    }
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#fff'
        },
        logo: {
            marginTop: 50,
            marginBottom: 80,
            width: 150,
            height: 40,
    
        },
        inputArea: {
            marginTop: 30,
            padding: 15,
            height: 60,
            width: 370,
            borderColor: '#808080',
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            borderRadius: 15
        },
        botao: {
            width: 350,
            height: 60,
            backgroundColor: '#000000',
            marginTop: 35,
            marginLeft: 8,
            borderRadius: 15,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
    
        },
        botaoText: {
            fontSize: 15,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: '#fff'
        },
        helloText: {
            fontSize: 40,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            marginTop: 15,
            color: '#000000',
            marginEnd: 120,
            marginTop: 8
        },
        welcomeText: {
            fontSize: 16,
            marginTop: 10,
            marginEnd: 35,
            marginVertical: 10,
            color: '#808080',
        },
        forgotPassword: {
            textDecorationLine: 'underline',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            marginTop: 15,
            marginBottom: 15,
            marginLeft: 30,
            fontSize: 12
        },
        Connected: {
            textDecorationLine: 'underline',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            marginTop: 15,
            fontSize: 12,
            marginRight: 55,
            marginLeft: -5
        },
        checkBoxStyle: {
            marginTop: 15,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            marginStart: -10
        },
        eye: {
            alignSelf: 'flex-end',
            bottom: 42,
            right: 40
        }
    })
    
    export default Login;
```

Comment: In your onOpen method you can do this --> modalizeRef?.current?.open()

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem

```js
function onOpen() {
    modalizeRef.current?.open();
}
```

This variable can be `null`, so, to fix it, change your code to:

```
function onOpen() {
     if (modalizeRef.current) modalizeRef.current.open();
}
```